# Dipole antenna length calculation -- why so much variation?

Tags: rf, antenna

Was checking few online calculators for dipole antenna length computation, and found that each tool, gave a different length. Is dipole construction based purely on heuristics, or is there some sound mathematical model to determine the dipole lengths ?

The two calculators, for instance, whose answers do not match -

- [Calculator #1](http://www.angelfire.com/mb/amandx/dipole.html)
- [Calculator #2](http://www.csgnetwork.com/antennaedcalc.html)

Any one of the two, which I could consider authoritative ?

Comment: @Mods, you could go ahead and close the question, as there was a misunderstanding on my part. See comment on accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so at 100 MHz, Calculator one yields a dipole antenna length of 4.68 feet, while calculator two give a length of 4.6822 feet. How closely do you expect them to match?

Comment: Thanks @Dave for taking time to answer, but I must've been very tired to have missed the decimal conversion of metric units. While one tool reported 6-1/4 inches for 900MHz, the other gave 0.52 feets. What I missed was converting feets into inches. So yeah, effectively the tools do agree.

Comment: No Problem. Unit conversions have stumped everyone once or twice...

Answer (score 0):

I plugged-in 100MHz and got 1.426m on both. One of us is being stupid and I'm not ruling out that it is me.

Comment: Nope @Andy, the stupid guy in this case, is writing this comment. See my clarification above as comments to Dave's answer.

Comment: @icarus74 LOL - I was beginning to have personal doubts!!